# Firebase pods not installing correctly

Tags: firebase, cocoapods

I am trying to install some Firebase pods into my project but I am getting the error message below in my Terminal window;

`[!] Unable to read the license file 'LICENSE' for the spec 'Firebase (6.21.0)'`

Here is my podfile;

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'UberTutorial' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for UberTutorial
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'GeoFire', '>= 1.1'

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I did...

1. Delete derived data.
2. Full clean with command + shift + K.
3. Build project again, still same error.
4. Delete derived data again.
5. Full clean again.
6. Comment out pod lines.
7. Do pod install.
8. Uncomment pod lines.
9. Do pod install.
10. Build project again - SUCCESS!!!